# Open UI created under Xamarin.Android from Xamarin.Forms Portable Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portability

I have a Xamarin.Forms Project. I have created a Home screen with 4 menu items in the portable project. One of the UI is created in Xamarin.Android Project. From the Home screen (Portable Project) on clicking of one of the menu item should open the UI from the Xamarin.Android project. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that comes to mind would be to create a class in the portable project that inherits a standard xamarin.forms page.

Then implement a page renderer for your custom page class in the android project and use it to render the native content as you wish.

[This tutorial / blog post demonstrates it nicely.](https://blog.xamarin.com/customize-your-xamarin.forms-app-with-pages-for-each-platform/)

Answer (score 1):

You can mix Xamarin.Android/Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms. Here are some examples for that:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Forms2Native

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Native2Forms